# Increase the size of the memory mapped file

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, memory-mapped-files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to dynamically expand a Memory Mapped File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096485/how-to-dynamically-expand-a-memory-mapped-file)

Hi, I have a tree-like data structure stored in a memory-mapped file in Windows and when I needed to insert a record I'm checking if it's free pointer
is closer to the file end. But the real problem is about resizing the file.

In the windows documentation, it is said that `CreateFileMapping' will resize the file according to its parameters. So I decided to use it as bellow.

```
#define SEC_IMAGE_NO_EXECUTE 0x11000000

static void resize_file(wchar_t * file_name,int size)
{
  hFile = CreateFile(file_name,GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,0,\
                     NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,\
                        NULL);
  if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
       MessageBox(NULL,L"resize_file CreateFile have been failed", szAppName,MB_OK);
      exit(0);
  }

  // open file mapping object //
  HANDLE hMap = CreateFileMapping(hFile,NULL,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE|SEC_IMAGE_NO_EXECUTE,0,size,NULL);

  // Close files and mapping //
  CloseHandle(hMap); 
  CloseHandle(hFile);
}
```

Will this work? I have a little guilty about this because I just open and remap the file and didn't flush it. Do I need to flush it and do any other operations too?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to dynamically expand a Memory Mapped File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096485/how-to-dynamically-expand-a-memory-mapped-file) + [How can I extend the length of a memory-mapped file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752579/how-can-i-extend-the-length-of-a-memory-mapped-file)

Comment: @RomanR.:  Those two possible duplicates have contradictory accepted answers (the first says it can't be done; the second gives two ways to do it).  The first answer uses dot-net rather than WinAPI, so it doesn't seem an appropriate choice as a duplicate.  The best option for a duplicate might be:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254637/windows-resize-shared-memory

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-createfilemappingw) says two things.

Firstly (in the "*Remarks*" section),

> If an application specifies a size for the file mapping object that is larger than the size of the actual named file on disk and if the page protection allows write access (that is, the `flProtect` parameter specifies `PAGE_READWRITE` or `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE`), then **the file on disk is increased to match the specified size of the file mapping object**. If the file is extended, the contents of the file between the old end of the file and the new end of the file are not guaranteed to be zero; the behavior is defined by the file system.

This basically means that your file on disk gets resized when you map it to a memory region larger than the file with the call to `CreateFileMapping()`, and fills it up with unspecified stuff.

Secondly (in the "*Return Value*" section),

> If the object exists before the function call, the function returns a handle to the existing object (**with its current size, not the specified size**), and `GetLastError` returns `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`.

To me, this means your call to `resize_file()` will have no effect if your file is already mapped. You have to unmap it, call `resize_file()`, and then remap it, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Remapping the file will of course invalidate any pointers into that data. To work around this problem I wrote a cross platform library that reserves a larger chunk of virtual address space. The file can then be grown into that reservation and any pointers you have remain valid. https://github.com/decodeless/mappedfile (for use in https://github.com/decodeless/writer).